# datatables returns Invalid json response when i am loading french text FROM database

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, datatables

I am getting this error only when I select a column which has French content in it. It may be a language issue. What can I do to avoid this error?

> DataTables warning: table id=example - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        /*"contentType": false,*/
        "ajax": '<?=base_url()?>'+"posts/get_html_posts"
    });
});
```

```html
<table id="example" class=" ui table" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>No</th>
            <th>Category Name</th>
            <th>Subcategoty Name</th>
            <th>Title En</th>
            <th>Title Fr</th>
            <th>Is Draft</th>
            <th>Edit</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
            <th>Website url</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Controller

```
public function get_html_posts()
    {
        require(APPPATH .'third_party/ssp.class.php' );
        $table = 'posts';
        $primaryKey = 'post_id';
        $columns = array(
            array('db' => 'post_id','dt' => 0),
            array( 'db' => 'category_id', 'dt' => 1 ),
            array( 'db' => 'subcategory_id',  'dt' => 2 ),
            array('db'=>'title_en','dt'=>3),
            array('db'=>'title_fr','dt'=>4),
            array('db' => 'is_draft','dt' => 5,"formatter"=>function($d,$row) {
                if($row['is_draft']==1)
                return "<spna class='ui orange label'>Draft</span>";
                else
                return "<spna class='ui green label'>Published</span>";
            }),
            array('db' => 'post_id','dt'=>6,"formatter"=>function($d,$row) {
                return "<a href='".base_url()."posts/edit/".$row['post_id']."' class='ui orange button padding-10'><i class='write icon margin-0'></i></a>";
            }),

            array('db'=>'post_id','dt'=>7,"formatter"=>function($d,$row) {
                return "<a href='#' class='ui red button padding-10' onclick='return delete_record(this.id)' id='".$row['post_id']."'><i class='remove icon margin-0'></i></a>";
            }),
            array('db'=>'post_slug','dt'=>8,"formatter"=>function($d,$row)
            {
                $web_url = "http://localhost";
                return "<a class='ui orange button padding-10' target='_blank' href=".$web_url.'category/'.str_replace('-','', $row['category_id']).'/'.$row['subcategory_id'].'/'.$row['post_id'].'/'.$row['post_slug']."><i class='expand icon margin-0'></i></a>";
            })

        );

        $sql_details = array(
            'user' => 'root',
            'pass' => '',
            'db'   => 'my_demo',
            'host' => 'localhost'
        );
        //header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode(
            SSP::simple( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns )
        );
    }
```

Comment: Can you also share the output of your ajax?

Comment: Sounds like you have an issue with the character encoding of your AJAX response. Please show the PHP code.

Comment: When i had to deal with french i had some issues with the use of single quotes, since single quotes appear in french sentences quite often.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yeah i also think that .and i have not used any character encoding in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced similar problem sometimes back.Make sure you get a valid json response.
This is best example where you can refer for all jquery datatables related queries.
[Jquery Datatables](http://mbahcoding.com/tutorial/php/codeigniter/codeigniter-simple-server-side-datatable-example.html)

My controller looked something like this:

```
public function inbox()
     {
         $data = array(
                    'receiverEmail' => $this->session->userdata['user_login']['loginEmail'],
            );
        $response = $this->mail_receive->inbox($data);

     $output = array(
                        "iTotalRecords" =>$this->mail_receive->totalRecords($data),
                        "iTotalDisplayRecords" => $this->mail_receive->totalRecords($data),
                         "aaData" => $response,
                );


        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($output);

     }
```

And this is where I made the ajax call

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var table = $('#inbox').dataTable( {


         "bServerSide": true,
         "sAjaxSource": "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Inbox_redirect/inbox",
         "bProcessing": true,
        "order": [],
         "bSortable" : true,
          "aaSorting": [[2, 'asc']],
         "sServerMethod": "GET",
         "columns" : [ 
            {"data" : "mailId"},
            {"data" : "mailSender"},
            {"data" : "mailSubject"},
            {"data" : "mailContent"},
            {"data" : "mailSendDate"} ],
        "columnDefs": [
        { 
            "targets": [ 0 ], //first column / numbering column
            "orderable": false, //set not orderable
        },
        ],

    } );
} );


</script>
```

Please post some more code so that it is easier to help you out!

Comment: i have implemented datatables using example https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/defer_loading.html

Comment: In your page, use utf8_encode() where appropriate to make sure values coming from a database or external files are properly encoded (try to set the encoding of the fields in your database to UTF8 as well)

Also, take a look at the htmlentities() function to parse special characters to html entities which may solve encoding issues as well.

Comment: i have already used utf8_encode() in the field where it contains french text and but where do i need to decode that content?

Comment: utf8_decode() ...use this in your controller and pass the decoded json string and hence ajax call can get valid json response after processing the data